# output in Line A and Line B?

Tags: c, linux, multithreading

What would be the output in Line A and Line B?
Do you think there is synchronization problem in updating the variable value?

```
#include <pthread.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
int value = 100;

void *thread_prog(void *param);

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
   pthread_t tid;
   pthread_create(&tid,NULL,thread_prog,NULL);
   pthread_join(tid, NULL);
   value= value + 100;
   printf("Parent value = %d\n",value); //Line A
}

void *thread_prog(void *param) {
   value = value + 100;
   printf("Child value = %d\n",value); // Line B
   pthread_exit(0);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Child value is 200 and Parent value is 300 always. pthread_join causes the main thread to wait until the other thread finishes executing. Both threads are acting on the same global variable. So the `thread_prog` thread increments value and prints 200. The `main` thread then increments value and prints 300.

The 2 threads aren't exactly parent and child threads. I believe based on your question, that you mean to use the `fork` method instead of `pthread_create`

Comment: hey this is a problem from a paper? thank you for supporting me. may i know if there any synchronization problem in updating the variable value

Comment: The question has been edited AND closed. Most of the code has been removed. Based on initial question, there was no sync problem. Idk if this is from some paper

Comment: restored the original question